# JDBC template Update method internal behavior

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, insert, jdbctemplate

If  when we need to table record update or insert always we call jdbctemplete update method. How is the identify the processes separately,  as a record update process and insert process. What is the internal behavior to identify the process as an update or insert.

is it query the table before insert or update or it have another mechanism to do it

Answer (score 1):

The spring jdbctemplate internally invokes the java.sql executeUpdate method, which can execute an insert , update, delete or ddl statements.

```
 executeUpdate(String sql)
```

Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.

More here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)